# How to remove ghost character devices?

Tags: kernel, input

Dears,

I installed a driver for a Xbox One controller. Unfortunately in this process a lot of "ghost devices" were installed too.

I want to remove these devices. I tried to remove from /dev/input but the files were created after reboot. Below, the ls -l in the input folder about the devices.

```
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13,  0 mai 17 10:35 js0
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13,  1 mai 17 10:35 js1
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13,  2 mai 17 10:35 js2
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13,  3 mai 17 10:35 js3
```

The output of hwinfo | grep -i xbox

```
      I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
  N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  P: Phys=
  S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input32
  U: Uniq=
  H: Handlers=event21 js0 
  B: PROP=0
  B: EV=b
  B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  B: ABS=1b

  I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
  N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  P: Phys=
  S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input33
  U: Uniq=
  H: Handlers=event22 js1 
  B: PROP=0
  B: EV=b
  B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  B: ABS=1b

  I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
  N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  P: Phys=
  S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input34
  U: Uniq=
  H: Handlers=event23 js2 
  B: PROP=0
  B: EV=b
  B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  B: ABS=1b

  I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
  N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  P: Phys=
  S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input35
  U: Uniq=
  H: Handlers=event24 js3 
  B: PROP=0
  B: EV=b
  B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  B: ABS=1b

  I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
  N: Name="PS/2 Generic Mouse"
--
  mouse buttons = 0
  mouse wheels = 0
  is_mouse = 0
  is_joystick = 0
unknown non-USB input device
bus = 3, name = Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver
  handlers = event21 js0
  key = 000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007fdb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  abs = 000000000000001b
  mouse buttons = 0
  mouse wheels = 0
  is_mouse = 0
  is_joystick = 1
bus = 3, name = Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver
  handlers = event22 js1
  key = 000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007fdb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  abs = 000000000000001b
  mouse buttons = 0
  mouse wheels = 0
  is_mouse = 0
  is_joystick = 1
bus = 3, name = Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver
  handlers = event23 js2
  key = 000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007fdb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  abs = 000000000000001b
  mouse buttons = 0
  mouse wheels = 0
  is_mouse = 0
  is_joystick = 1
bus = 3, name = Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver
  handlers = event24 js3
  key = 000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007fdb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  abs = 000000000000001b
  mouse buttons = 0
  mouse wheels = 0
  is_mouse = 0
  is_joystick = 1
bus = 17, name = PS/2 Generic Mouse
  handlers = mouse3 event25
  key = 00000000000700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  rel = 0000000000000003
--
  P: /devices/virtual/input/input32
  L: 0
  E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input32
  E: SUBSYSTEM=input
  E: PRODUCT=3/45e/719/100
  E: NAME="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  E: PROP=0
  E: EV=b
  E: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  E: ABS=1b
  E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v045Ep0719e0100-e0,1,3,k130,131,133,134,136,137,138,139,13A,13B,13C,13D,13E,2C0,2C1,2C2,2C3,ra0,1,3,4,mlsfw
  E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6132401
  E: ID_INPUT=1
  E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
  E: ID_SERIAL=noserial
  E: TAGS=:seat:

--
  P: /devices/virtual/input/input33
  L: 0
  E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input33
  E: SUBSYSTEM=input
  E: PRODUCT=3/45e/719/100
  E: NAME="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  E: PROP=0
  E: EV=b
  E: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  E: ABS=1b
  E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v045Ep0719e0100-e0,1,3,k130,131,133,134,136,137,138,139,13A,13B,13C,13D,13E,2C0,2C1,2C2,2C3,ra0,1,3,4,mlsfw
  E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6082508
  E: ID_INPUT=1
  E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
  E: ID_SERIAL=noserial
  E: TAGS=:seat:

--
  P: /devices/virtual/input/input34
  L: 0
  E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input34
  E: SUBSYSTEM=input
  E: PRODUCT=3/45e/719/100
  E: NAME="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  E: PROP=0
  E: EV=b
  E: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  E: ABS=1b
  E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v045Ep0719e0100-e0,1,3,k130,131,133,134,136,137,138,139,13A,13B,13C,13D,13E,2C0,2C1,2C2,2C3,ra0,1,3,4,mlsfw
  E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6084124
  E: ID_INPUT=1
  E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
  E: ID_SERIAL=noserial
  E: TAGS=:seat:

--
  P: /devices/virtual/input/input35
  L: 0
  E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/input/input35
  E: SUBSYSTEM=input
  E: PRODUCT=3/45e/719/100
  E: NAME="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
  E: PROP=0
  E: EV=b
  E: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
  E: ABS=1b
  E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v045Ep0719e0100-e0,1,3,k130,131,133,134,136,137,138,139,13A,13B,13C,13D,13E,2C0,2C1,2C2,2C3,ra0,1,3,4,mlsfw
  E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6086508
  E: ID_INPUT=1
  E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
  E: ID_SERIAL=noserial
  E: TAGS=:seat:
```

Does anyone can help?

Environment

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Linux 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: And you want to remove them because...?

Comment: Because they are disturbing when I'm playing games (some games create "ghost" players performing the same movements).